# Launch Content in PhoneGap Android App

Tags: android, cordova

I like to launch my app from a link, link could be shared via web, whatsup or facebook. I like to open the content in my app if app is not installed then it should redirect to android play store. I google lot and pointing me to webintent. Sample I'm seeing is to open Google Map frommy App but I like to open my app through a html link. Is there a unique way to launch the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with custom url schemes, I think this is what you need.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

It allows to open your app when another app or web uses a custom link like

> myapp://

And It also accept parameters

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(intent);